# What is best approach to configure react js app with asp .net core web api

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have created react-js app using create-react-app tool
And I have .net core web API
When ever I'm calling web api i have to do something like 
fetch('localhost://7000/api/something') each time 
I want to avoid the repetitive use of 'localhost://7000'
So Is there any way to configure react js app 
So that I can avoid this localhost string in every file whenever I'm utilizing web api?

Comment: Share us the code how you request web api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `fetch`, it accepts absolute url and relative url. But for relative url, it is according the base url for hosting `create-react-app`.

For a workaround, you may try define a variable to store the `localhost://7000` and then reference it from `fetch`.

Comment: You mean I have to create one file where I can store my api url and import this file whenever i need right?

Comment: @BhushanDhage yes.